# Routing many conflicting paths

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, graph-visualization

In our project we have to visualize a network. The network consists of multiple devices, each of which has multiple ports. A device is visualized as a box containing each port lined up next to each other. Each port can have a link to any other port on any other device. Each link has to be routed in a way that it does not run over any device if at all possible and that it does not cross other links if possible.

Currently we use an A* pathfinding to find a route for each link. Grid nodes occupied by devices have a very high weight. After pathfinding for one link is finished, we add a lower weight to each grid node occupied by the path of this link.

This kind-of works, but the order in which the pathfinding is done greatly affects the outcome and often this results in very sub-optimal paths. One common mistake that this makes is that multiple paths running in the same direction tend to cross more often than necessary.

This here is one example:
A is connected to C and B is connected to D.

```
A|
B++
 ||
 ++---C
  +---D
```

What happens here is that pathfinding for the link from A to C is run first. The path starts at A, runs straight downwards until it is at the same height as C, then it turns right until it gets to C.

Now pathfinding for the link from B to D runs. It first has to jump over the first link to get to free space where it can move without penalty. Then it turns downwards and again has to jump over the first path again, before it can reach the same height as D, where it turns right to get to D.

There is also a solution that does not require any jumps at all.

Now my question: is there any algorithm that allows to find an optimal (or at least a good) solution when searching for multiple paths at the same time? Kind of, a non-greedy algorithm for finding competing paths?

I am not concerned about implementations or libraries, I am just looking for a fitting algorithm.

Edit: One important thing I forgot: This should only affect the positioning of the edges. The position of the devices and thus of the ports is set by the user and are thus not allowed to be modified by the algorithm.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X01002232) proves that the edge-disjoint paths problem (similar to or the same as your problem) is NP-hard even for a very restricted class of graphs (specifically, series-parallel graphs).  I would have to read it carefully to be 100% sure, but I'm fairly confident this means that there is unfortunately no efficient (polynomial-time) algorithm for solving your problem.

Comment: This problem is NP-hard if one is looking for the true optimal solution. I'm sure that "good" solutions can be found using a heuristic algorithm. I'm a fan of using permutation genetic algorithms. In this approach, links are inserted in a random order. A heuristic determines a best route based on the links already inserted. Different insertions orders will result in better or worst solutions. The genetic algorithm will combine good solutions in order to arrive at better solutions.